# How to keep text from going behind an image

Tags: html, css, image, floating

I am trying to keep my top-bar navigation from going behind my logo image on the header of my page. See below an example of the page when it is maximized in my screen:

[Maximized View](http://content.screencast.com/users/ChristopherY/folders/Jing/media/a5e80a8f-8e23-4f3c-8a8c-db5ff360764d/2014-01-31_1057.png)

Here is what it looks like when the browser window is made smaller:

[Smalller Screen Example](http://content.screencast.com/users/ChristopherY/folders/Jing/media/5ee2995c-e6a7-4ec8-b6b7-63f9a2393142/2014-01-31_1059.png)

I am trying to fix this page so that the top nav-bar that currently runs behind the image when the window is made smaller, will instead move and extend to the right.

Any ideas? The site is Inhishands.com

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide us with some code? or a jsfiddle? We cant help you without some code..

Comment: change the z-index of the menu bar to a higher number than the image

Comment: You could get clever if you're comfortable enough and have some CSS using the viewport type/size to determine whether to show the full menu or a collapsed version which drops down instead of moving to the right. I can give more information on this if you need

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the menu (`<ul id="display">`) has the CSS property `float:right`, so it will always be positioned relative to the right side of the screen.  When the screen is made smaller, the right side moves closer to the left, so the menu moves leftwards too (and overlaps the logo).

If what you want is for the menu to always start from the right side of the logo (and not to overlap it), then you could give it the property `float:left` and add a margin to its left side (like `margin-left:370px`).  There are other ways of positioning it (like using absolute positioning) but this will get the job done.

Comment: If his issue is the layering of the elements I think it would be more likely that it is a z-index issue. Especially if the page is supposed to scale - floating right could be necessary.

Comment: The OP said that when the page is made smaller, they want the menu to "move and extend to the right," which implies to me that they want it to stay positioned to the right of the logo, not overlapping it.  I think it's a positioning issue, not a z-index issue (though I agree that the post title implies the opposite).

Comment: OK, it's a bit confusing all right lol... edit your post a little and I'll remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use Z-index on the navigation. In the CSS, set the z-index of the hands image lower than that of your navigation and you will see the navigation on top instead of behind.

Here's some information on Z-Index in case you need it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

Nice design.

First of all you need to fix the minimum width of the top menu HEADER in your CSS.
Fix the header min-width according to the resolution you need:

```
#Header{
min-width: 1237px;
}
```

or directly into the HTML

```
<div id="Header" style="min-width: 1237px">
```